# How much is a sim card at heathrow, and what network should i use

Tags: cellphones

Travelling into heathrow in April , Have an IPhone 6 4g how much will a sim card cost,  pay as you go. Data calls and text. will it have a uk tel number?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't speak for Heathrow specifically, **pay-as-you-go SIM cards are widely available in supermarkets in the UK**. They're usually either at the till or behind the counter, so you might have to ask the cashier.

They're usually "free" in that you pay £10 and get £10 of credit on the card. If there is an extra charge, it won't be more than a few pounds.

For pay-as-you-go, I can personally recommend Three, as their default plan is better value than most in the UK. Calls are 3p/min, texts are 2p and data is 1p/MB (so a £10 top-up gets you 1GB of data). However, they don't always have the best coverage outside towns and cities.

To answer your last question, **yes, the SIM card will have a UK telephone number**.

Edited to add: [this page has details on the best value prepaid (PAYG) SIM cards for lots of countries](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Prepaid_SIM_with_data).